# tcl database insertion and retrieval slow

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I am new to tcl. I have connected to an SqLite Database.

I have around 100,000 records which i want to insert into database after computation. I use the following command to insert records into database 100,000times.

I am sure i am doing something wrong here. What would be the appropriate way to do this?

For insertion:

```
db eval {insert into table values(value1,value2,value3,value4)}
```

For retrieval i have to do select operation at least 1000 times, things are terribly slow:

```
db eval {select x as x, y as y from table} {
   set z  [expr $z + $x + $y]
}
```

Comment: Are you putting the `db eval {select ...} {...}` in a loop, or is it just dealing with a thousand rows in the result?

Answer (score 2):

By default each insertion is a single transaction.  This is very slow.  You can group your insertions together into single transactions of, say, 100 insertions, and speed things up greatly.

```
db eval { BEGIN TRANSACTION }

... do some insertions ...

db eval {  END TRANSACTION }
```

or

```
db transaction {

... do some insertions ...

}
```

Out of the box, SQLITE is extremely safe, but quite slow. If you know what you are doing, and are willing to risk db corruption on a disk crash, then there are several optimization you can do that provide spectacular speed improvements.

In particular:

- Switch off synchronization  ( PRAGMA synchronous = OFF; )
- Group writes into transactions
- Index tables
- Use database in memory

If you have not explored all of these, then you are likely running many times slower than you might.

Comment: This works well for insertions. Is there a way to speed up selects?

Comment: In general, selects are fast which means there is less opportunity to optimize them.  Have you looked at the answer I linked?  The next thing to try would be switching off synchronization.  But I suspect that will not improve selects.

Comment: I have looked at the sample select statement you posted.  Are you sure that the bottleneck is in sqlite?  How long does TCL take to execute 1000 times set z  [expr $z + $x + $y]?

Comment: Actually, file opening corresponds to creating a connection (i.e., the `db` handle). Transactions are still expensive though; starting one is largely equivalent to getting a lock on a file region, and committing one corresponds to, among other things, a full flush to disk. Very expensive! Taking the DB out of the default auto-commit mode is a huge win.

Comment: And Tcl's SQLite interface has an extra bonus feature: syntactic transaction support. Use like this: `db transaction { ... do some insertions ...}`. Successful completion of the code results in a commit, thrown exceptions result in a rollback. Easy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the sqlite part of the question because I haven't used sqlite in a few  years, but one cause of performance degradation is your expr statement. You need to brace the arguments to expr, which should speed up that portion of your loop considerably:

```
set z [expr {$z + $x + $y}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doing single inserts from Tcl into an sql table is not the fastest way to accomplish what you want.

To speed things up you should write the table you want into an external file and slurp the data in
with a single db statement.

You'd write the data out like so:

```
set fh [open temp_file w]
set rowid 0
# loop
  puts $fh [join [list $value1 $value2 $value3 $value4] \t]
# end loop
close $fh
```

Then, using the [copy](http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#copy) method, you can read everything in one shot:

```
db copy replace values temp_file
```

And as for calculating a sum, I don't know why you're not using sql itself to do the summation.  There are many examples on the web of how to do that.  Here [are](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_sum-multiple.php) [a](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php) [couple](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp).  I imagine your sql statement would be something like:

```
db select sum(x+y) from table
```

or possibly

```
db select sum(x+y) as z from table
```

Comment: I have to use some values which i compute in the program with the values i get from table also.